# Angular: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl

Tags: javascript, html, angular, forms, typescript

I am trying to add a form field with custom telephone number input control. I used the example of the phone from https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/examples.

Here is the code:

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <example-tel-input placeholder="Phone number" required></example-tel-input>
  <mat-icon matSuffix>phone</mat-icon>
  <mat-hint>Include area code</mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>
```

```
import {FocusMonitor} from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
import {coerceBooleanProperty} from '@angular/cdk/coercion';
import {Component, ElementRef, Input, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';
import {MatFormFieldControl} from '@angular/material';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs';

/** @title Form field with custom telephone number input control. */
@Component({
  selector: 'form-field-custom-control-example',
  templateUrl: 'form-field-custom-control-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['form-field-custom-control-example.css'],
})
export class FormFieldCustomControlExample {}

/** Data structure for holding telephone number. */
export class MyTel {
  constructor(public area: string, public exchange: string, public subscriber: string) {}
}

/** Custom `MatFormFieldControl` for telephone number input. */
@Component({
  selector: 'example-tel-input',
  templateUrl: 'example-tel-input-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['example-tel-input-example.css'],
  providers: [{provide: MatFormFieldControl, useExisting: MyTelInput}],
  host: {
    '[class.example-floating]': 'shouldLabelFloat',
    '[id]': 'id',
    '[attr.aria-describedby]': 'describedBy',
  }
})
export class MyTelInput implements MatFormFieldControl<MyTel>, OnDestroy {
  static nextId = 0;

  parts: FormGroup;
  stateChanges = new Subject<void>();
  focused = false;
  ngControl = null;
  errorState = false;
  controlType = 'example-tel-input';
  id = `example-tel-input-${MyTelInput.nextId++}`;
  describedBy = '';

  get empty() {
    const {value: {area, exchange, subscriber}} = this.parts;

    return !area && !exchange && !subscriber;
  }

  get shouldLabelFloat() { return this.focused || !this.empty; }

  @Input()
  get placeholder(): string { return this._placeholder; }
  set placeholder(value: string) {
    this._placeholder = value;
    this.stateChanges.next();
  }
  private _placeholder: string;

  @Input()
  get required(): boolean { return this._required; }
  set required(value: boolean) {
    this._required = coerceBooleanProperty(value);
    this.stateChanges.next();
  }
  private _required = false;

  @Input()
  get disabled(): boolean { return this._disabled; }
  set disabled(value: boolean) {
    this._disabled = coerceBooleanProperty(value);
    this.stateChanges.next();
  }
  private _disabled = false;

  @Input()
  get value(): MyTel | null {
    const {value: {area, exchange, subscriber}} = this.parts;
    if (area.length === 3 && exchange.length === 3 && subscriber.length === 4) {
      return new MyTel(area, exchange, subscriber);
    }
    return null;
  }
  set value(tel: MyTel | null) {
    const {area, exchange, subscriber} = tel || new MyTel('', '', '');
    this.parts.setValue({area, exchange, subscriber});
    this.stateChanges.next();
  }

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder, private fm: FocusMonitor, private elRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>) {
    this.parts = fb.group({
      area: '',
      exchange: '',
      subscriber: '',
    });

    fm.monitor(elRef, true).subscribe(origin => {
      this.focused = !!origin;
      this.stateChanges.next();
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.stateChanges.complete();
    this.fm.stopMonitoring(this.elRef);
  }

  setDescribedByIds(ids: string[]) {
    this.describedBy = ids.join(' ');
  }

  onContainerClick(event: MouseEvent) {
    if ((event.target as Element).tagName.toLowerCase() != 'input') {
      this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('input')!.focus();
    }
  }


  }
```

example-tel-input-example.html

```
  <div [formGroup]="parts" class="example-tel-input-container">
      <input class="example-tel-input-element" formControlName="area" size="3">
      <span class="example-tel-input-spacer">&ndash;</span>
      <input class="example-tel-input-element" formControlName="exchange" size="3">
      <span class="example-tel-input-spacer">&ndash;</span>
      <input class="example-tel-input-element" formControlName="subscriber" size="4">
    </div>
```

But I get the following error:

> ERROR Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.

Comment: Please make sure **MatInputModule** is imported.

https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7898

Comment: @KimwanOgot Your solution fixed for me. thanks

Answer (score 53):

Need to `import` two module and add those in imports and exports section.

```js
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';

@NgModule ({
  imports: [ MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule ],
  exports: [ MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule ]
})
```

And the most thing which everybody miss this `'/'` character. if you see the  [Angular Material Documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview) , they also miss this (Last Checked 16 Jun 2020, don't know they even updated or not). I make an example for clarifications

```html
<!-- Wrong -->
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput>
</mat-form-field>

<!-- Right -->
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput />
</mat-form-field>
```

Look at the snippet carefully. when `<input` begin it must close with `/>` but most people miss the `/` (backslash) character.

Comment: oh wow thank you so much, copied their example right off the page and couldn't get it to work!

Answer (score 28):

Make sure **MatInputModule** is imported and `<mat-form-field>` contains `<input>` with `matInput / matSelect` directives.

https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7898

Answer (score 13):

Import `MatInputModule`, solved my error

Answer (score 6):

You need to specify your class as a provider for `MatFormFieldControl`

https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control#providing-our-component-as-a-matformfieldcontrol

```
@Component({
  selector: 'form-field-custom-control-example',
  templateUrl: 'form-field-custom-control-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['form-field-custom-control-example.css'],
  providers: [
    { provide: MatFormFieldControl, useExisting: FormFieldCustomControlExample }   
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Also, don't forget to write the name attribute in the input tag:

```
name="yourName"
```

Answer (score 4):

1. if you are using any 'input' tag in your code along with 'mat-form-field', make sure to include 'matInput' in the input tag
2. if there is any *ngIf present in child tag of 'mat-form-field', specify the *ngIf condition in 'mat-form-field' tag

Comment: Thanks , very helpful

Answer (score 3):

Another possible issue closing the input tag. If you copy code from one of the Angular examples (https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview), you may end up with the code:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

The input should have the close tag (slash):

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" />
```

Answer (score 3):

This will fix your issue

```
 import {
      MatFormFieldModule, 
      MatInputModule
    } from "@angular/material";
```

Answer (score 0):

Error says that `mat-form-field` should contain at least one form field from which input is taken.

Ex : `matInput` `mat-select` etc.

In your case you may add `matInput` tag to your input fields within example-tel-input-example.html. And also you could move `mat-form-field` inside `example-tel-input-example` component and add it against each `matInput` field.

```
<div [formGroup]="parts" class="example-tel-input-container">
      <mat-form-field>
         <input matInput class="example-tel-input-element" formControlName="area" size="3">
      </mat-form-field>
      <span class="example-tel-input-spacer">&ndash;</span>
      <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput class="example-tel-input-element" formControlName="exchange" size="3">
      </mat-form-field>
      <span class="example-tel-input-spacer">&ndash;</span>
      <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput class="example-tel-input-element" formControlName="subscriber" size="4">
      </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

**Note** : `mat-icon` or `mat-hint` cannot be considered as form-fields